# Pagination in IONIC 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pagination, ionic2

thanks for all the help!.
In this oportunity, I need to create a pagination for a grid (like google pagination or something like that) and show only 10 or 20 rows in the current page.
I can't find anything for ionic 2, only pagination with infinite scroll.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to have a Subject which can act as both a publisher and a subscriber.

- Create a service that can get you the pages with simple Http calls.
- Use a subject that can be used as both a publisher and a subscriber.
- Use *ngFor with the async pipe.
- publish using the Subject using the next() method and have the *ngFor listen to the Observable.

  Sample code:-

//subject that can be used as a publisher and a subscriber

```
private paginationGetter: Subject <Product[]> = new Subject <Product[]> ();
private paginationGetter$: Observable <Product[]> = this.paginationGetter.asObservable();
```

return the paginationGetter$ in the method that returns the pages and use paginationGetter.next(data) to publish the new data and then display it using a code similar to:-

```
ion-col *ngFor="let item of items | async">
```

Note that items refer to:     `paginationGetter$` and async pipe is necessary for         `*ngFor` to be able to display observables.

Please, refer to a live example here:-

[Pagination Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/z5yMbldrPisWuSlrifB9?p=preview)

Hope that helps

Comment: Is there any documentation about that? Because the origin of my data is from a service too. I need to use 2 services? One for the data and one for the pagination?
Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, just the same service you get the data from, you can use for pagination. Sure, there is documentation about this, but it is a little bit scattered. On which area exactly do you need documentation?

Comment: I can't do it, I'm a little confused. Do you have some documentation with examples about pagination?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have developed one myself for you. Please, refer to edited answer